# IF statement with variable in google Apps Script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, var

I am trying to make a google spreadsheet document with some buttons in it for a few colleagues. The colleagues can indicate which silo they're working with by pressing a certain button. In this case, it is either 1, 2, 3 or 4. This value is then stored in a cell. Afterward, they can keep track of their production by pressing a plus or minus button every time they have produced a pallet of material. The amount of pallets produced is stored in a cell (in this case 'M4:M5'). Now  I want to keep track of the number of pallets produced from each silo. So when they have selected silo 1, I want the number of pallets produced stored in a cell next to silo 1. When they select a different silo, I want to keep track of the pallets produced from that silo. I hope you kinda get what I am talking about.

I want to do this by using an If statement. So if silo 1 is selected, and they press the plus button because a pallet has been produced, I want a pallet to be added to a certain cell I made for silo 1. I tried to do this by storing the selected silo number as "temp" and then verifying it with an "if" statement. If it matches a certain silo number, the right cell will have a +1 added to it. The problem is that Apps Script is telling me that "temp" is unused in my code.

I am totally new to this coding language. Can someone please help me?

```
function PlusHVBB() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var tempHVBB = spreadsheet.getRange('M4:M5').getValue();
spreadsheet.getRange('M4:M5').setValue(tempHVBB+1);
var temp = spreadsheet.getRange('P4:P5').getValue();
if (temp = 1){

spreadsheet.getRange('C29').setValue(tempHVBB+1);
}
```

};

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem is that you use `getValue()` on a range that contains more than one cell and that your [comparison operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) is incorrect

- The problem with your `if` condition is that `temp = 1` does not compare the value of `temp` against `1`, but rather assigns it the value `1`. To compare it against `1` you need to use the `==` or `===` operator: `if (temp == 1)`

Furthermore:

- 'M4:M5' is a range that contains two cells
- You need to either get (and set!) the value of each single cell indvidually:

```js
var tempHVBB1 = spreadsheet.getRange('M4').getValue();
var tempHVBB2 = spreadsheet.getRange('M4').getValue();
```

- Or you can use the methods [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) respectively to retrieve and set values from a range of cells. This will return you a nested array or values in the format `[[row1/column1, row1/column2],[row2/column1, row2/column2]]` or in your case: `[['M4', 'M5']]`